# when is Big-Oh(n) = Omega(n) ? Is it same as theta(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

This question looks simple to me, but just wanted to see whether i am moving in the right direction.

Is it as simple as saying when n =1  ??

Comment: What do you mean by *"Is it as simple as saying when n =1 ??"*?

Comment: I meant trivial case.. when number of inputs is 1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, if `f is BigO(g)` and `f is Omega(g)` then `f is BigTheta(g)`. In fact, this is exactly the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) of `BigTheta`.

To apply that to algorithms, if an algorithm is both `BigO(n^2)` and `Omega(n^2)` for example, then it is `BigTheta(n^2)`. And if it is `BigTheta(n^2)` then is is `BigO(n^2)` and `Omega(n^2)`.